# TypeError: get_members() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given (I actually gave 2)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discum

I am making a bot and it has a method in it called `get_members()` which takes 2 args `self and client`. I am supplying both arguments and still it says I am providing 3 args.

Also the client parameter shows a warning **Unexpected Argument**

**The stacktrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinesh\Documents\GitHub\DMBot\lib\scraper.py", line 18, in fetch
    self.scrape()
  File "C:\Users\Vinesh\Documents\GitHub\DMBot\lib\scraper.py", line 14, in scrape
    self.scraped = self.get_members(self, client)
TypeError: get_members() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post your code - [mre].

Comment: You don't pass the `self` argument.  It is passed implicitly for object methods.  So, just use `self.get_members(client)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the self argument when are calling the method, python already acknowledge the self argument, you dont need to pass again, so you code should be:

```
self.scraped = self.get_members(client)
```

if your client is inside your class you need to pass the self argument on your client. So you code will be:

```
self.scraped = self.get_members(self.client)
```

Answer (score 3):

`self` cannot be passed by you. It is passed implicitly by Python.

```
self.get_members(client)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the first argument `self`, since `get_members` is already a method, `self` it is already passed implicitly when you call it, so you need to do: `self.get_members(client)`